# How can I include a subquery Result in output when using IN clause in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
select x.Currency,x.ProductID,x.Quantity,x.Channel
from
(
select distinct l.Channel, l.Quantity,l.Currency
from Products l
and l.ProductID in (select distinct pc.ProductID
                    FROM Tags pc
                    where pc.Tags in
                        (
                            'T1',
                            'T2',
                            'T3'
                        )
                    )
) x
GROUP BY x.Currency,x.ProductID,x.Quantity,x.Channel
```

Is there a way to include the the Tag that matched in the IN clause along with the output?

So I can have Tag as a column in my output table.

Tried to change it to:

`select(distinct pc.ProductID,pc.Tag)` but does not work.

Comment: If you add tag, you have to group it as well. Does this what you want?

Comment: For the subquery, why not change to use JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select Tag, you can change subquery to use JOIN. However, the column in the select statement must be the same as in group by. Thus, you have to group the tag as well

```
SELECT x.Currency, x.ProductId, x.Quantity, x.Channel, x.Tags
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT a.Channel, a.Quantity, a.Currency, pc.Tags
    FROM Products a
    JOIN Tags pc ON pc.ProductId = a.ProductID
    WHERE pc.Tags IN('T1','T2','T3')
) x
GROUP BY x.Currency, x.ProductID, x.Quantity, x.Channel, x.Tags
```